# What do you call this in English when you buy something or get something and celebrate it by drinking alcohol?

Tags: phrase-choice

What do you call this English when you buy something or get something and celebrate it by drinking alcohol? Do you have any verbs or phrases for it?
I cannot to find the word in English. But the most close phrase I found is *wet the baby's head*. So can I apply the word *wet* for things. For example:

> Let's wet my new cam.

In Russian, by the way, people call it *замачить*. Literally that means to soak something.

Comment: As with most "what is the word" questions.  Please: 1. State if the word exists in your native language. 2. Tell us what the word is in your native language. 3. Describe the result of looking up that word in a bilingual dictionary.

Comment: You mean celebrate something like "graduating from college" or "buying a house"?

Comment: I edited the question. It can be either. It even can be buying a new phone

Comment: I should let you know that "Let's wet my new cam." will probably not be understood by most speakers of English. I think the most similar sentiment might be something like, "Let's drink to my new cam." or "Let's *toast* to my new cam." I'm pretty sure anything with "Let's wet ..." [baby's head, cam, or other] doesn't work in English.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are asking for a word like "Prost!" (German) and "¡Salud!" (Spanish).

When you drink (can be alcohol or whatever) to celebrate, we often say "to have a toast to".

When you clang the mugs together like in a table for celebration, people often say "Toast!", "Cheers!", "Toast/Cheers to [the success]".

For example:

You and your friends are celebrating your birthday and are drinking beer around a table. A friend of yours can stand up, hold up a beer mug and say "Toast to [your] birthday!" and everyone clangs their mugs together.

This usually goes with alcohol but you can do the same thing with any other drink.

Update:

Since the OP edited their question to specify that they want something similar to " замачить " (Let's wet my new cam.), which is Russian, I'll add that you can say "Let's drink to [the event]!" to propose a celebration with alcohol.

For example: "*Let's drink to* Sam's birthday!" or "*Let's have a drink to* Sam's birthday", which are proposing that we celebrate Sam's birthday (the event) by drinking (most likely alcohol).

Comment: I don't think this is the meaning the OP wants. (For OP's benefit, this answer translates **за здоро́вье**.) I think what is meant instead is something along the lines of "let's go **break in** my new (whatever)" but with a specific reference to drinking alcohol in celebration rather than actually using the (whatever).

Comment: I *did* say I was assuming so the OP can ```accept``` my answer if it solved answered what they meant to ask. Also, my answer was before they edited the question to include the example of "let's wet my new cam", which doesn't really make sense in English when trying to celebrate something.

Comment: Fair enough - I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: I've also edited my answer to include the OP's edit.